# SQL for begin and end of data rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got the following table:
[image]

and I was wondering if there is an SQL query, which would give me the begin and end Calender week (CW), where the value is greater than 0.
So in the case of the table above, a result like below:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a group by counting the number of zeros and then aggregating:

```
select article_nr, min(year), max(year)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when amount = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by article_nr order by year) as grp
      from t
     ) t
where amount > 0
group by article_nr, grp;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select Atricle_Nr, min(Year&CW) as 'Begin(Year&CW)',max(Year&CW) as 'End(Year&CW)' 
from table where Amount>0 group by Atricle_Nr;
```